# Javascript prevent looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I know that probably someone asked this before, but i just can't find the right answer. 
i want to prevent this function from looping:

```
var counter = 0;
var height, length, sec, inner;  
var links = $('.projects li');
var containers = $('.projects .container');

$('.container #prev').click(function(){
    counter = (--counter) < 0 ? length - 1 : counter%length;
    console.log(counter);
    inner.stop().animate({top: -counter*height }, 800);
//this is where it loops
});

$('.container #next').click(function(){
    counter = (++counter) < 0 ? length - 1 : counter%length;
    console.log(counter);
    inner.stop().animate({top: -counter*height }, 800); 
//this is where it loops
});

links.click(function(){
    var index = links.index(this);
    var container = $(containers[index]);
    $(".projects_menu").css({'display':'none'});
    container.addClass('active');
    inner = container.find('.inner');
    sec = container.find('section');
    length = sec.length; 
    if (length < 2) {
        console.log(1);
        $('.container #prev, .container #next').css({'display':'none'});
    }
    height = $('.container').height();


});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: There seems to be multiple problems with your code: e.g. `length` is undefined when used in click-handlers, possible multiple handlers react on same event because bubbling isn't stopped... . To get a satisfying answer you should show your html too or/and make a fiddle.

Comment: can you fiddle the task ?